# Where can I find gtkmm4 sources?

Tags: source, gtk, source-code

I need to install gtkmm4 where do I find its sources. I am using archlinux.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](http://gtk.10911.n7.nabble.com/ANNOUNCE-gtkmm-3-93-0-unstable-td93360.html), [v3.9x.y](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm/tree/3.93.0) will become Gtkmm 4.0. So I can get the 3.93.0 [tarball](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm/-/archive/3.93.0/gtkmm-3.93.0.tar.bz2).